# Why still Hibernate does its logging (eg SQL) in synchronous mode (if enabled)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-5.x

Wondering why still Hibernate SQL loggings happening in simple synchronous mode and hence have a performance hit rather than doing it asynchronously (like how we can do using log4j2 for example).

Comment: Hibernate just uses the jboss-logging API, which is just a facade. You can plug whatever real logging system into jboss-logging. If the logging system you choose to plug in is asynchronous, then hibernate logs will be asynchronous.